# For $\sigma=(1,2,\dots,n)\in S_n$, I need to show if $\tau\in S_n$ commutes with $\sigma$ then $\tau=\sigma^k$ for some $k\ge 1$.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

$\sigma=(1,2,\dots,n)\in S_n$, I need to show if $\tau\in S_n$ commutes with $\sigma$ then $\tau=\sigma^k$ for some $k\ge 1$

Thank you for help. I only knew only disjoint cycles commutes .

Comment: Disjoint cycles commute, not *only* disjoint cycles.

Comment: Now i understand that you mean the cycle $1\to2\to3\to... \to n\to 1$.... sorry, I hadn't in mind this (other) convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* If $\sigma\in C_{S_n}(\tau)$ (that is, of $\sigma$ commutes with $\tau$ is $S_n$), then, in particular, we have $$\begin{align}
\tau(12\dots n)\tau^{-1}&=(\tau(1)\tau(2)\dots\tau(n)) \\
&=(12\dots n).
\end{align}$$